# Decode JSON with JQuery

Tags: jquery, actionscript-3, json, jsonp

my explorations into jquery are proving a little frustrating.

I am receiving the following Json back from the server.

```
{"status":"ok",
"0":{"ID":"1","location":"location info"},
"1":{"ID":"2","location":"location info"},
"2":{"ID":"3","location":"location info"},
...etc
});
```

I need to put all the objects except the status into an array.
 I achieved this in AS3 as follows, but don't seem to be able to get any where near using jquery.

```
public function ResultToArray(jsonString:String):Array
{
var jObj:Object = JSON.decode(jsonString);
var objects:Array = [];
for each(var obj:Object in jObj)
{
    if(obj is String)break;
    objects.push(obj);
}
return objects;
}
```

I would like to put each of the objects in an array.

The following only loops over one object.

```
      $(data).each(function(index)
    {
    alert(data[index]["location"])  
    });
```

Please pardon my ignorance.
If I could receive any advice It'd be much appreciated.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do again? just get the objects without the status?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what it is you want to do? Show some js code. Show an error, something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var o = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonString),
        myObjects = [];
for (var c in o) {
    if (c != 'status')
        myObjects.push(o[c]);
}
```

Possibly you could check `(typeof o[c] == 'object')` if you don't want to check for 'status'.

Comment: you probably want `JSON.parse`

Comment: @Raynos - no joy there. It passes JSLint but fails to parse.

Comment: OK, thanks that worked if I use  var o = data; and not try to parse the json - many thanks

Answer (score 4):

If I understand well, your JSON could be improved to help you out here. Instad of storing each location as a zero-based integer index, why not store them in a JSON array:

```
{
    "status":"ok",
    "locations":[
        { "ID":"1", "location":"location info"},
        { "ID": "2", "location": "location info" },
        { "ID": "2", "location": "location info" },
        ...etc
    ]
}
```

Then, with jQuery all you need to do is parse the JSON and extract the `location` parameter, which is already an array:

```
// Assume jsonString is retrieved from an AJAX call:
var locationObj = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
var locations = locationObj.locations;
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm beginning to think the same thing as I'm struggling to parse the JSON - it just quietly fails.

Comment: I think it's a better paradigm to follow, since you're essentially going to end up using `locations` as an array anyway. How are you encoding the JSON on the server: using PHP's `json_encode()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to fetch data remotely and have it turned into a Javascript object.